# partial mocking with Moq and Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, moq, castle-windsor, ioc-container

> versions    Castle Windsor 3.3.0.0      Moq 4.2.1507.118

it appears that Moq comes with *CallBase* setting that, when enabled, delegates calls to any non-setup methods down to base object.

```
var mock = new Mock<MyService> {CallBase = true};
```

unfortunately as soon as I register it with Castle Windsor, all non mocked methods are returning a null immediately, underlying logic is no longer called.

```
         Container.Register(Component
            .For<MyService>()
            .Instance(mock.Object)
            .LifeStyle.Singleton
            );
```

I tried a few different lifestyles as well.

so when I do this:

```
mock.setup(x => x.SomeMethod).Returns(myMockedData);
```

this works as expected:

```
Container.Resolve<MyService>().SomeMethod();
```

but now this returns a null:

```
Container.Resolve<MyService>().AnotherMethod();
```

as soon as I remove the mock registration, AnotherMethod starts working as before.

**more specific code example**

```
public class Auth : IAuth
{
   // mocked succesfully
   public IEnumerable<T> AuthorizeData<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)  { ... }

    // never gets called
    public virtual List<User> GetAllUsers() {
        return new List<User>{new User{FIRST_NAME = "test"}};
    }
}
```

mock method

```
    protected static Mock<T> GetMock<T>() where T : class {

        var mock = new Mock<T> {CallBase = true, DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock};
        IoC.Container.Register(Component
            .For<T>()
            .Instance(mock.Object)
            .LifeStyle.Transient
            );
        return mock;
    }
```

mock setup

```
GetMock<IAuth>().Setup(x => x.AuthorizeData(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<DO>>()))
                .Returns((IEnumerable<DO> data) => data); // pass through input data (do not authorize
```

to sum up again, AuthorizeData is mocked successfully, GetAllUsers() returns an empty list. and original class never gets called

Answer (score 2):

`CallBase` doesn't control how return values are generated. For that, you'll need to set the `DefaultValue` property:

```
var mock = new Mock<MyService> { CallBase = true, DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
```

The default value for `DefaultValue` (sic.) is `DefaultValue.Empty`, so that's the reason you'll need to explicitly set it to `DefaultValue.Mock`.

When you do that, the `mock` will return other proxy values from methods without explicit setups. If the return value is a concrete type, Moq will attempt to create a value of that type, but it'll only do that if that type has a parameterless constructor. If no parameterless constructor exists, it'll throw an exception when you try to call the method.

---

You may want to look into turning Castle Windsor into an [Auto-Mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container).

---

Based on the comments below, I can't reproduce the issue. Assuming that `AuthorizeData` is `virtual` (which it isn't above, but which the comments claim), this test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void Repro()
{
    var td = new Mock<Auth>
    {
        CallBase = true,
        DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock
    };
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<Auth>().Instance(td.Object));

    td
        .Setup(a => a.AuthorizeData<string>(new string[0]))
        .Returns(new[] { "foo", "bar" });

    Assert.Equal(
        new[] { "foo", "bar" },
        container.Resolve<Auth>().AuthorizeData(new string[0]));
    Assert.NotEmpty(container.Resolve<Auth>().GetAllUsers());
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for writing. the only behavior change I am seeing so far with this property set is that my method returns an empty list instead of null. my breakpoint inside the actual service is not hit, leading me to believe it is still not passing the call through

Comment: @SonicSoul Which list? What type?

Comment: Mark, I mean when calling Container.Resolve<MyService>().AnotherMethod(); this method returns a List of Person type object. There is no setup for this method, so my understanding of CallBase is that it should be calling underlying class, but my underlying class never gets called. I have a breakpoint there which never gets hit. I am suspecting the issue may be with the way the mock is registered with Castle Windsor ?

Comment: @SonicSoul Please share `MyService`.

Comment: As given, `AuthorizeData` can't be overridden, since it isn't virtual, so I can't reproduce the issue. Also, can you [please slim down the repro code](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I've made that method virtual and there is no change in behavior. example simplified.

Comment: @SonicSoul I can't reproduce the issue. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks so much for trying to reproduce! what version of Mock / Castle Windsor are you on ? I will update my answer with  my versions..

Comment: @SonicSoul It's with Windsor 3.3.0 and Moq 4.2.1510.2205.

Comment: maybe that's it.. I'll try upgrading castle windsor

Comment: crap. brought in Castle Windsor 3.3.0.0 but no improvement to my predicament.

Comment: tried a few more things, made every public method virtual. also tried stepping into constructor (parameterless) which never gets called, and tried removing the ctor altogether